# Trouble with right arrow key

Tags: linux, expect

I have a expect script that is giving me troubles using the right arrow.
The goal of my script is to install a program automatically for our customers.

Using autoexpect to test the right arrow key returns:

send -- "^[\[C"

my script (expect version 5.43.0):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
if [ catch "spawn /mnt/install.sh" reason ] {
  send_user "failed to spawn /mnt/install.sh script: $reason\n"
  exit 1
}

expect {
    timeout { send_user "Timeout reached! Aborting..."; return}
    eof     { send_user "\r\nInstallation complete!!\r\n"; return}
    "*Demo*Expiration*Date*Reached*" {
       sleep .5
       send -- "^[\[C";
       sleep .5
       send "\r";
       exp_continue
    }
}
```

I keep receiving the following error message when the block of code within
"*Demo*Expiration*Date*Reached*" executes:

missing close-bracket while compiling "send -- "^[\[C"

I think I'm missing something basic here.....

Thx!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^[` is probably meant to be a single character (Escape). and you probably need to send a literal backslash and open bracket, both of which need to be esacped. Try:

```
send -- "\033\\\[C"
```

Comment: Let me add that mine worked with TERM=linux, won't work as vt100